# What's a good mechanism to move from global state to patterns like dependency injection?

Tags: oop, testing, design-patterns, refactoring

### Background

I'm in the process of reworking and refactoring a huge codebase which was written with neither testability nor maintainability in mind. There is a lot of global/static state going on. A function needs a database connection, so it just conjures one up using a global static method: `$conn = DatabaseManager::getConnection($connName);`. Or it wants to load a file, so it does it using `$fileContents = file_get_contents($hardCodedFilename);`.

Much of this code does not have proper tests and has only ever been tested directly in production. So the first thing I am intending on doing is write unit tests, to ensure the functionality is correct after refactoring. Now sadly code like the examples above is barely unit testable, because none of the external dependencies (database connections, file handles, ...) can be properly mocked.

### Abstraction

To work around this I have created very thin wrappers around for example the system functions, that can be used in places where non-mockable function calls were used before. (I'm giving these examples in PHP, but I assume they are applicable for any other OOP language as well. Also this is a highly shortened example, in reality I am dealing with much larger classes.)

```
interface Time {
    /**
     * Returns the current time in seconds since the epoch.
     * @return int for example: 1380872620
     */
    public function current();
}

class SystemTime implements Time {
    public function current() {
        return time();
    }
}
```

These can be used in the code like so:

```
class TimeUser {
    /**
     * @var Time
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * Prints out the current time.
     */
    public function tellsTime() {
        // before:
        echo time();

        // now:
        echo $this->time->current();
    }
}
```

Since the application only depends on the interface, I can replace it in a test with a mocked `Time` instance, which for example allows to predefine the value to return for the next call to `current()`.

### Injection

So far so basic. My actual question is how to get the proper instances into the classes that depend upon them. From my Understanding of [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), services are meant to be passed down by the application into the components that need them. Usually these services would be created in a {{main()}} method or at some other starting point and then strung along until they reach the components where they are needed.

This model likely works well when creating a new application from scratch, but for my situation it's less than ideal, since I want to move gradually to a better design. So I've come up with the following pattern, which automatically provides the old functionality while leaving me with the flexibility of substituting services.

```
class TimeUser {
    /**
     * @var Time
     */
    private $time;

    public function __construct(Time $time = null) {
        if ($time === null) {
            $time = new SystemTime();
        }

        $this->time = $time;
    }
}
```

A service can be passed into the constructor, allowing for mocking of the service in a test, yet during "regular" operation, the class knows how to create its own collaborators, providing a default functionality, identical to what was needed before.

### Problem

I've been told that this approach is unclean and subverts the idea of dependency injection. I do understand that the true way would be to pass down dependencies, like outlined above, but I don't see anything wrong with this simpler approach. Keep in mind also that this is a huge system, where potentially hundreds of services would need to be created up front (Service locator would be an alternative, but for now I am trying to go this other direction).

Can someone shed some light onto this issue and provide some insight into what would be a better way to achieve a refactoring in my case?

Comment: Do you really need to make a `Time` and a `SystemTime` class? You are overengineering this. A simple function that either returns the time or a fixed number (depending on if testing is turned on) will work just fine. Then just search/replace `time()` with `time2()` and done. What you are trying to write will be utterly unreadable, and the OO version of spaghetti code.

Comment: Ariel, the `Time` example is of course a contrived one. I don't want to post lengthy production code here. Replace the `Time` with something like Database or Request/Response, and you have the same problem.

Comment: You are never going to mock the database connection since you need an actual database on the other end. At best you will use a different database server - which you will have automatically by changing the configuration variables in your test environment. And even for something more complicated you don't need this, you are overdoing it. Time is pretty much the only non-deterministic input, everything else you should be able to test without changing the code, and just giving the functions fixed arguments.

Comment: 1. I may very well mock the database connection, if I am writing an actual unit test. And even if its not the database connection. What about any other network connection. Of course that will be mocked in a test.
2. It's still not about these examples I'm giving here. My question is about the more general concept. Please don't hang yourself onto these examples so much. I'm much more interested in an answer to my actual question.

Comment: You will mock the database and pretend to parse SQL commands? Just use a real database, with test data. Same for the network connection - connect to a real device configured for testing (whatever it might be). Test at a high level, not at the level of each function.

Comment: Hopefully someone else will answer your actual question, I'm a fan of answering the actual question even if there is a better way. But since I can't answer the question I will at least tell you that there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Hi t.heintz, this is not an easy question to answer because you say its a large project that you have inherited. You should ask your self, do you want to invest time writing code that you know is a band aid to your problem, or do you want to refactor small units of code, if its possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you telling your managers you are doing when they ask?

Comment: Ira, luckily my manager is fully up to date on this and understands why this is a neccessary step (they eventually got fed up with not being able to test). I am calling the process simply refactoring or renewing the old system.

Answer (score 2):

I think You've made first good step.
Last year I was on DutchPHP and there was a lecture about refactoring, lecturer described 3 major steps of extracting responsibilyty froma god class:

1. Extract code to private method (it should be simple copy paste since
   $this is the same)
2. Extract code to separate class and pull
   dependency
3. Push dependency

I think you are somewhere between 1st and 2nd step. You have a backdoor for unit tests.
Next thing according to above algorithm is to create some static factory (lecturer named it ApplicationFactory) which will be used instead of creation of instance in TimeUser.
ApplicationFactory is some kind of ServiceLocator pattern. This way you will inverse dependency (according to SOLID principle).
If you are happy with that you should remove passing Time instance into constructor and use ServiceLocator only (without backdoor for unit tests, You should stub service locator)
If you are not, then You have to find all places where TimeUser is being instantiated and inject Time implemenation:

```
new TimeUser(ApplicationFactory::getTime());
```

After some time yours ApplicationFactory will become very big. Then You have to made a decision:

1. Split it into smaller factories
2. Use some dependency injection container (Symfony DI, AurynDI or
   something like that)

Currently my team is doing something similar. We are extracting responsibilities to seperate classes and inject them. We have an ApplicationFactory but we use it as service locator at as hight level as possible so classes bellow gets all dependencies injected and don't know anything about ApplicationFactory. Our application factory is big and now we are preparing to replace it with SymfonyDI.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a good *mechanism* to do this.

You've described some stages you might force the program to go through to accomplish this, but you are still apparantly planning to do this by hand at apparantly a very high cost.

If you really want to get this done on a huge code base, you might consider automating the steps using a program transformation engine:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation

Such a tool can let you write explicit rules for modifying code.  Done right, this can make code changes reliably.  That doesn't minimize your need for testing, but can let you spend more time writing tests and less time hand-changing the code (erroneously).

Comment: You're correct, I am planning to do this manually, as I don't trust an automated process to properly complete such a task. I am looking for a strategy (probably the better term) to do this by hand, but efficiently and correctly.